# How to combine GitLab variable expansion with YAML anchors?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I've got something like this in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
.templates:
  - &deploy-master-common
    script:
      - ansible-playbook … --limit=${environment:name}.example.org
    environment:
      url: https://${environment:name}.example.org
…
deploy-master1:
  <<: *deploy-master-common
  environment:
    name: master1
  only:
    - master
```

When running the deploy-master1 job, unfortunately, `${environment:name}` is expanded to the empty string. Is this sort of expansion not supported by YAML/GitLab CI?

---

I can't tell yet whether this is a GitLab or YAML restriction, but it looks like **the `environment` hash is being replaced rather than merged.** Moving `<<: *deploy-master-common` to the bottom of `deploy-master1` I get the following error message from the GitLab CI lint API endpoint:

```
.gitlab-ci.yml is not valid. Errors:
[
  "jobs:deploy-master1:environment name can't be blank"
]
```

Comment: For YAML the scalar `ansible-playbook … --limit=${environment:name}.example.org` is nothing special and it doesn't know about expanding that, that is done by gitlab. The position of the merge key in a mapping should not matter, according to the YAML specification. So this looks like undefined behaviour by gitlab (maybe trying to resolve the `${}` expansion on the fly during loading of the YAML, where they should do a post-processing pass after loading)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this with custom variables because the template doesn't specify any:

```
.templates:
  - &deploy-master-common
    script:
      - ansible-playbook … --limit=${environment_name}.example.com
    environment:
      name: $environment_name
      url: https://${environment_name}.example.com
…
deploy-master1:
  <<: *deploy-master-common
  variables:
    environment_name: master1
  only:
    - master
```